# ¿Cómo obligar al usuario de tu app en Java (android studio) tener que actualizarla?

Tags: app, google-play, google-play-services, actualizacion

Actualizo la aplicación en el `play store` y el usuario es necesario que la actualice para seguir utilizándola.

¿Cómo puedo incorporar un pequeño mensaje en pantalla cuando esté una actualización disponible evitando que la use o simplemente que use la App pero que le salga un aviso de actualización.

Comment: Usa alguna consulta al servidor al iniciar la app y segun la información que devuelva añade la pantalla bloqueante

Comment: Sí, sé que tengo que comunicar la versión del Play Store con la que usa el usuario pero eso es posible?

Comment: Hay una forma de hacerlo mediante una api de google https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates